# Trying to trigger a script to run on a specific date and time

Tags: javascript

Trying to trigger a script to run on a specific date and time, I am trying the code below but getting this error (Already setting up a recurring clock trigger. (line 6, file "Code")

any ideas on how to fix this?

```
ScriptApp.newTrigger('submit')
.timeBased()  
.atDate(2016,9,1)
.atHour(2)
.create();
```

Comment: Umm do you want it to run on any browser that is open at the time? Or are you trying to save something like in a database?

Comment: Looking for it to add a trigger inside of scripts, I am running it on a spreadsheet. So when I hit the debug button it adds it inside of my triggers

Comment: Figured it out myself                                                                                 // Triggers on 12-1-16 at 7:00am, 0 = January
{var triggerDay = new Date(2016, 11, 1, 7);
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('getGoogleSpreadsheetAsExcel')
.timeBased()  
.at(triggerDay)
.create();
}

Comment: I've added what I think is the appropriate tag to this question, because this is not just about JavaScript, but specific to the libraries provided by Google Apps Script. Please do correct if I'm wrong.

Comment: no you are right thank you

Answer (score 0):

Here is the correct code I was looking for, just in case anyone needs it

```
    // Triggers on 12-1-16 at 7:00am, 0 = January
{var triggerDay = new Date(2016, 11, 1, 7);
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('getGoogleSpreadsheetAsExcel')
.timeBased()  
.at(triggerDay)
.create();
}
```